# Streaming upload to google cloud storage from multipart section

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-cloud-storage, streaming, asyncfileupload

In an ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API, I'm trying to upload file to google cloud storage. Based on [this](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/mvc/models/file-uploads/samples/3.x/SampleApp/Controllers/StreamingController.cs) example, I have:

```cs
var boundary = MultipartRequestHelper.GetBoundary(
    MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(uploadObject.Request.ContentType),
    _fileUploadOptions.MaximumBoundaryLimit);

var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, uploadObject.Request.Body);
var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync(cancellationToken);
var hasContentDispositionHeader = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(
    section.ContentDisposition,
    out var contentDispositionHeader);

using var client = await StorageClient.CreateAsync(_credential);

var body = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object
{
    Bucket = _storageOptions.DefaultBucketName,
    ContentDisposition = contentDispositionHeader.Name.Value,
    Name = "test.mp4"
};

var result = await client.UploadObjectAsync(body, section.Body,
                                            cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

where:

```cs
uploadObject.Request is HttpRequest
```

This code throws an error

> The format of value 'bytes 0-945000/0' is invalid

If I do something like this:

```cs
using var ms = new MemoryStream();
await section.Body.CopyToAsync(ms, cancellationToken);
```

before `client.UploadObjectAsync`, this code will run successfully.

In the [Microsoft example](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/mvc/models/file-uploads/samples/2.x/SampleApp/Utilities/FileHelpers.cs#L149), they also has `ProcessStreamedFile` function which called before upload process.

So my question is what this exception means and how I can fix it? Also is it necessary to use `section.Body.CopyToAsync` before using `section.Body` in `client.UploadAsync`?

Thank you in advance